# Facebook Application Domains issue

Tags: facebook, url

I have a really weird error and I don't know from where comes, I'd already setup everything for the Facebook Application Domains but according with Facebook I don't

[image: You can see it here]

But I already have the configuration right

[image: as you can see here]

I really don't know what happened, it's something with the server? Is it because my URL have the information Private? Is it an issue with HostGator? Please help, you can test it here: https://getcogas.com/fb.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your information in all pages are correct.[image][image]

PS .You must define valid url in 
**"Valid OAuth redirect URIs"**

Comment: everything is valid and defined, and I still have the error, is my domain blacklisted?